# ansible - fail when the result.stdout has more than 1 row

Tags: ansible

I would like to fail when the result.stdout has more than 1 lines / row

```yaml
tasks:
  - shell: command
    register: result
    
  - fail:
    when: result.stdout has more than 1 lies / row
```

`result.stdout` looks like this

```
0:1:0
0:1:1
0:1:2
0:1:3
0:1:4
0:1:5
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with `stdout`, the `shell` module also provides you a list [`stdout_lines`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#return-stdout_lines) which is:

> The command standard output split in lines.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#return-stdout_lines*</sup>

So you can achieve this using the Jinja [`length`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#length) filter on this list:

```yaml
- fail:
  when: result.stdout_lines | length > 1
```